# Selenium WebDriver- Test a login function using Excel file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have an excel file which has 4 rows of data. But it always get 3 rows only(row count taken as 3). 
If I update the field int startRow = 1; it is starting from 1st row and get 3 rows from 1st. If I update the field int startRow = 2; it is starting from 2nd row and get 3 rows from 2nd.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelUtils {

    private static XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet;
    private static XSSFWorkbook ExcelWBook;
    private static XSSFCell Cell;

    public static void setExcelFile(String Path,String SheetName) throws Exception {
        try {
            FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(Path);
            ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
            ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
        } catch (Exception e){
            throw (e);
        }
    }

    public static Object[][] getTableArray(String FilePath, String SheetName, int iTestCaseRow)    throws Exception
    {   
        String[][] tabArray = null;
        try{
            FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
            ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
            ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
            int startRow = 1;
            int startCol = 1;
            int totalRows = ExcelWSheet.getLastRowNum();
            int totalCols = 2;
            tabArray=new String[totalRows][totalCols];

            for (int i=startRow; i<=totalRows;i++) {                  
                for (int j=startCol; j<=totalCols;j++){
                    tabArray[i-1][j-1]=getCellData(i,j);
                    System.out.println(tabArray[i-1][j-1]);  
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not read the Excel sheet");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not read the Excel sheet");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return(tabArray);
    }

    public static String getCellData(int RowNum, int ColNum) throws Exception{
        try{
            Cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);
            String CellData = Cell.getStringCellValue();
            return CellData;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return"";
        }
    }

    public static String getTestCaseName(String sTestCase)throws Exception{
        String value = sTestCase;
        try{
            int posi = value.indexOf("@");
            value = value.substring(0, posi);
            posi = value.lastIndexOf(".");    
            value = value.substring(posi + 1);
            return value;
            }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw (e);
        }
    }

    public static int getRowContains(String sTestCaseName, int colNum) throws Exception{
        int i;
        try {
            int rowCount = ExcelUtils.getRowUsed();
            for ( i=0 ; i<rowCount; i++){
                if  (ExcelUtils.getCellData(i,colNum).equalsIgnoreCase(sTestCaseName)){
                    break;
                }
            }
            return i;
        } catch (Exception e){
            throw(e);
        }
    }
    public static int getRowUsed() throws Exception {
        try{
            int RowCount = ExcelWSheet.getLastRowNum();
            return RowCount;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            throw (e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pat Meeker - When startRow = 0, it displays an error, "SKIPPED: testLogin" and it is not execute the program.

Comment: Thank you all, its my fault, i have given a wrong path for Excel sheet, my code is ok now.